# Reading attribute usage in property?

Tags: c#, reflection

How do you read property based attributes at run time using Reflection in C#?

---

I have created a class similar to this:

```
public class PictureField
{
  public IList<Cropping> Croppings { get; set; }
}

public class Cropping
{
  public int Width { get; set; }
  public int Height { get; set; }
  public string Device { get; set; }
  public string SrcSet { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically control the list of Croppings on an instance of my PictureField class via attribution.  I want the parent object to be able to control this.  For example, I want to be able to do this:

```
public class ResponsiveHeroImage
{
  public string AltText { get; set; }

  [CropPoint(1920, 640, "Desktop", "(min-width: 1260px)")]
  [CropPoint(1259, 640, "Tablet", "(min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1259px)")]
  [CropPoint(758, 384, "Mobile", "(max-width: 959px)")]
  public virtual PictureField ResponsiveImage { get; set; }
}

public class ResponsiveBlockImage
{
  public string AltText { get; set; }

  [CropPoint(1024, 540, "Desktop", "(min-width: 960px)")]
  [CropPoint(758, 384, "Mobile", "(max-width: 959px)")]
  public virtual PictureField ResponsiveImage { get; set; }
}
```

so I have created an attribute like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CropPointAttribute : Attribute
{
  public CropPointAttribute(int width, int height, string device, string srcSet)
  {
    this.Width = width;
    this.Height = height;
    this.Device = device;
    this.SrcSet = srcSet;
  }

  public int Width { get; }
  public int Height { get; }
  public string Device { get; }
  public string SrcSet { get; }
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to read the `CropPoint` attribute from within my `PictureField` class.  How can I get a handle on the parent object and read the attributes they have declared?

Comment: You access attributes from a Type (using typeof() or GetType()). If you need to know what type of object contains a given PictureField *from within* a PictureField instance, then you will need to pass that info into it, say on construction. You might also consider other options like having a generic PictureField<T> type with T being one of several classes which have a set of CropPoint attributes (on the class), though I think that pushes the boundaries of attributes since at that point you may as well define them in code (in sub-types of PictureField) and not metadata.

Comment: For anyone curious in the future... This was for the Episerver CMS.  Turns out you can use a custom `EditorDescriptor` to read this information and pass it to your custom dojo widget in edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is anyway to access the attributes from `PictureField`. However, you can access the property from `ResponsiveBlockImage` and `ResponsiveBlockImage` with its attributes. You can pass the values directly from the code instead of doing so by assigning attribute. Why would you go with attributes?